# Pytessaract fails to detect even after expanding

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I used pytesseract for detecting text:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as py

def img_to_str(loc : str):
    img = cv2.imread(loc)
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=30, fy=30)
    py.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
    data = py.image_to_string(img)
    print(data)

img_to_str(r"C:\Users\user1\Documents\second.jpg")
```

The image is :
[image: here]

I went expanding it to 30 times but no use in doing so.

Output:

What might the way to do then?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[paddleocr](https://pypi.org/project/paddleocr/)** library, it seems to work better. I tested your uploaded image and it had a pretty good detection with good confidence too.

[image]