# YOLO model isn't giving expected result

Tags: python, deep-learning, yolo

I used a trained model found in github

model : [SVHN](https://github.com/icns-distributed-cloud/YOLOv5-SVHN)

As given in readme.md,

my main.py:

```
import torch
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageEnhance as ImageEnhance
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img
import numpy as np
from math import *

model = torch.hub.load('icns-distributed-cloud/yolov5-svhn', 'svhn').fuse().eval()
model = model.autoshape()
img1= Image.open(r"C:\Users\user1\Documents\third.jpg")
# Prediction
h,w=img1.size
pred=[]
filter1=ImageEnhance.Color(img1)
img1=filter1.enhance(0.0)
img1=img1.resize((h*10,w*10))
img1.show()

def predict(i,j,h,w):
    cropped_img = img1.crop((i, j, i+h, j+w))
    f=model(cropped_img)
    if f[0]!=None and f[0][0][4]<=0.4:
        predict(i,j-w,h,w)
        predict(i,j,h,w+w)
        predict(i-h,j,h,w)
        predict(i,j,h*2,w)
    if f[0]!=None and f[0][0][4]>=0.4:
        img2=np.array(cropped_img)
        cv2.rectangle(img2,(round(f[0][0][0].item()),round(f[0][0][1].item())),(round(f[0][0][2].item()),round(f[0][0][3].item())),(255,100,0),6)
        plt.imshow(img2)
        plt.title('class : '+str(f[0][0][5].item())+" \n confidence : "+str(f[0][0][4].item()))
        plt.show()
    return f

for i in range(0,h*10,h):
    for j in range(0,w*10,w):
        f=predict(i,j,h,w)
        if f!=None:
            pred.append(f)

for i in pred:
    if i[0]!=None:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2, conf, clas in i[0]:
            if conf>0.3:
                print('box: ({}, {}), ({}, {})'.format(x1, y1, x2, y2))
                print('confidence : {}'.format(conf))
                print('class: {}'.format(int(clas)))
                '''
                print((int(x1/10),int(y1/10)),(int(x2/10),int(y2/10)))
                cv2.rectangle(img2,(int(x1/10),int(y1/10)),(int(x2/10),int(y2/10)),(255,0,0),3)
                plt.imshow(img2)
                plt.show()
                '''
```

The image which I used is :

[image: third.jpg]

hence, obviously my expectation is 4,8,4,6.

Initially it detected only 4 as the image isn't clear. for this purpose, I converted RBG image to gray scale. resized the image, cropped and then resized.

but now, my output is :

```
Using cache found in C:\Users\Sanmitha/.cache\torch\hub\icns-distributed-cloud_yolov5-svhn_master

                 from  n    params  module                                  arguments
  0                -1  1      3520  models.common.Focus                     [3, 32, 3]
  1                -1  1     18560  models.common.Conv                      [32, 64, 3, 2]
  2                -1  1     19904  models.common.BottleneckCSP             [64, 64, 1]
  3                -1  1     73984  models.common.Conv                      [64, 128, 3, 2]
  4                -1  1    161152  models.common.BottleneckCSP             [128, 128, 3]
  5                -1  1    295424  models.common.Conv                      [128, 256, 3, 2]
  6                -1  1    641792  models.common.BottleneckCSP             [256, 256, 3]
  7                -1  1   1180672  models.common.Conv                      [256, 512, 3, 2]
  8                -1  1    656896  models.common.SPP                       [512, 512, [5, 9, 13]]        
  9                -1  1   1248768  models.common.BottleneckCSP             [512, 512, 1, False]
 10                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
 11                -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample    [None, 2, 'nearest']
 12           [-1, 6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
 13                -1  1    378624  models.common.BottleneckCSP             [512, 256, 1, False]
 14                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]
 15                -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample    [None, 2, 'nearest']
 16           [-1, 4]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
 17                -1  1     95104  models.common.BottleneckCSP             [256, 128, 1, False]
 18                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 2]
 19          [-1, 14]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
 20                -1  1    313088  models.common.BottleneckCSP             [256, 256, 1, False]
 21                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 2]
 22          [-1, 10]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
 23                -1  1   1248768  models.common.BottleneckCSP             [512, 512, 1, False]
 24      [17, 20, 23]  1     43152  models.yolo.Detect                      [11, [[10, 13, 16, 30, 33, 23], [30, 61, 62, 45, 59, 119], [116, 90, 156, 198, 373, 326]], [128, 256, 512]]
Model Summary: 191 layers, 7.28206e+06 parameters, 7.28206e+06 gradients

Fusing layers... 
Model Summary: 140 layers, 7.27349e+06 parameters, 7.27349e+06 gradients
Adding autoShape...
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py:504: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at ..\aten\src\ATen\native\TensorShape.cpp:3484.)
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
box: (0.0, 0.19499744474887848), (137.242431640625, 128.22288513183594)
confidence : 0.30603668093681335
class: 1
box: (52.23253631591797, 0.0), (190.0, 70.11492156982422)
confidence : 0.41145217418670654
class: 2
box: (54.806610107421875, 3.3701179027557373), (190.0, 278.511474609375)
confidence : 0.4895976781845093
class: 7
box: (55.85855484008789, 0.3548659086227417), (190.0, 197.8501739501953)
confidence : 0.365851491689682
class: 8
box: (0.0, 0.0), (140.3123779296875, 216.81472778320312)
confidence : 0.3351562023162842
class: 4
box: (53.156036376953125, 0.0), (190.0, 72.2713851928711)
confidence : 0.40216246247291565
class: 7
box: (0.0, 0.0), (130.40765380859375, 213.34080505371094)
confidence : 0.3830447793006897
class: 6
box: (51.61797332763672, 0.0), (190.0, 70.91419982910156)
confidence : 0.31078973412513733
class: 7
```

The detected images are

[image: figure1]
[image: figure2]
[image: figure3]
[image: figure4]
[image: figure5]
[image: figure6]
[image: figure7]
[image: figure8]
[image: figure9]
[image: figure10]
[image: figure11]
[image: figure12]
[image: figure13]

I don't know why this detects other things as digits with good confidence but fails to detect digits with good confidence...

Kindly help me

Answer (score 2):

You can try out text recognition, something like OCR which needs no training.
Just run through your images and get the o/p and maybe add a simple fuzzy match filter.
[image]

Comment: I had tried py tessaract. But of no use

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76643071/pytessaract-fails-to-detect-even-after-expanding check this

Comment: Try **paddleocr** library

Answer (score 0):

First use CRAFT: Character-Region Awareness For Text detection to identify the texts in your image. Then pass the cropped text image to OCR like Tesseract to extract the texts from image.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can update this code, it should work for you

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


# Download and load the YOLOv5 SVHN model
model = torch.hub.load('icns-distributed-cloud/yolov5-svhn', 'svhn').fuse().eval()
model = model.autoshape()

# Preprocess the input image
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((640, 640))  # Resize to the model's input size
    image = torch.from_numpy(np.array(image)).float() / 255.0  # Normalize pixel values between 0 and 1
    image = image.permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension and rearrange channels
    return image


# Perform inference
def recognize_numbers(image_path):
    image = preprocess_image(image_path)
    with torch.no_grad():
        prediction = model(image, size=640)
    return prediction


# Draw bounding box on image copy
def draw_box(image_path, box, output_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    original_width, original_height = image.size
    print(f"image size: {original_width}x{original_height}")
 
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = box
    x1 = int(x1 * original_width / 640)
    y1 = int(y1 * original_height / 640)
    x2 = int(x2 * original_width / 640)
    y2 = int(y2 * original_height / 640)
    print(f"new drawable box ({x1},{y1},{x2},{y2})")
    draw.rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), outline='green', width=3)
    image.save(output_path)

    
# Provide the path to your image
image_path = '/tmp/IDbCb.jpg'
   
# Call the function to recognize the numbers in the image
prediction = recognize_numbers(image_path)

# Find the box with the highest confidence
highest_confidence = 0

best_box = None
best_class = 0
for pred in prediction[0][0]:
    x1, y1, x2, y2, conf, cls = pred[:6].tolist()
    if conf > highest_confidence:
        highest_confidence = conf
        best_box = (int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2))
        best_class = cls

if best_box:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = best_box
    print('Box: ({}, {}), ({}, {})'.format(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    print('Class: {}'.format(int(best_class)))
    print('Highest Confidence: {}'.format(highest_confidence))
else:
    print('No box found with confidence above the threshold.')


output_path = '/tmp/image-1.png'  # Change the output path and file name as per your requirement

draw_box(image_path, best_box, output_path)
```